# Emacs - Python Indent in parenthesis

Tags: python, emacs

My default python mode in emacs indents the following multiline code this way:

```
mydict = {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
}
```

which is okay as of [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)

I' d rather use the following style:

```
mydict = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    }
```

which is also ok with PEP8.

How do I tell emacs to indent the last parenthesis accordingly to the beginning of the previous line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install the latest python-mode.el (from https://launchpad.net/python-mode).

In the latest version 6.1.4, the PEP8 "indent-alternatives when closing a list" is implemented (see [release notes](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-mode/2014-January/001593.html).)

In your case, you don't have to customize it, and just accept the default.

By default, `py-close-at-start-column-p` is `nil`, which looks like:

```
my_list = [
     1, 2, 3,
     4, 5, 6,
     ]
result = some_function_that_takes_arguments(
     'a', 'b', 'c',
     'd', 'e', 'f',
     )
```

Comment: This does not help as the values are already set correctly by the python mode. It indents everything the right way except for the last parenthesis

Comment: And you added the commas? (your original post is unchanged--the code is erroneous...)

Comment: Yes, sorry. so the first codeblock in my post is how my emacs24 indents the whole stuff. If I press the `TAB` button with the cursor in the line of the last parenthesis, it stays at the beginning of the line

Comment: Okay, I see. I added solution: installing ``python-mode.el`` latest version.